# Tasks freezing the interface

Tags: c#, task

I am using 3 Tasks to execute 3 tasks simultaneously, however, when started all the tasks there is no freezing of the GUI, it only gets a bit slow ... when it returns the result of the last task it totally freezes and stops updating the GUI ...

```
async Task UpdateBlockChain()
        {
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew((Action) =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    BlockChain blockChain = new BlockChain();
                    coinList[0].Price = blockChain.GetDataByNode("last");
                    coinList[0].Low = blockChain.GetDataByNode("low");
                    coinList[0].High = blockChain.GetDataByNode("high");
                    RefreshView();
                    Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            await Task.Delay(500);
        }

        async Task UpdateBitFinex()
        {
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew((Action) =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Bitfinex bitFinex = new Bitfinex();
                    coinList[1].Price = bitFinex.GetDataByNode("last_price");
                    coinList[1].Low = bitFinex.GetDataByNode("low");
                    coinList[1].High = bitFinex.GetDataByNode("high");
                    RefreshView();
                    Task.Delay(2000);
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            await Task.Delay(500);
        }

        async Task UpdateBitstamp()
        {
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew((Action) =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Bitstamp bitstamp = new Bitstamp();
                    coinList[2].Price = bitstamp.GetDataByNode("last");
                    coinList[2].Low = bitstamp.GetDataByNode("low");
                    coinList[2].High = bitstamp.GetDataByNode("high");
                    RefreshView();
                    Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
```

Refresh View:

```
void RefreshView()
        {
            if (dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                dataGridView1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    dataGridView1.Update();
                    dataGridView1.Refresh();
                }));
            }
        }
```

Run task:

```
await UpdateBlockChain();
await UpdateBitFinex();
await UpdateBitstamp();
```

Here is a example of class https://pastebin.com/DuQybhcz

I do not know the methods I am using are wrong, I apologize for code flow error.

Comment: What .NET version are you using? If it is 452 then you should be using `Task.Run(() => {})` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: im using NET 4.5.1

Comment: Always do `await Task.Delay()`

Comment: Since you don't wait in your infinite loops (as @DennisKuypers said), you are flooding the UI.

Comment: @L.B, you are totally right, of course this is because of there is no await inside the while loops - these tasks become overly CPU intensive, however still if they would not run on UI thread - the UI would not freeze, so, technically my answer is not completely off :-)

Comment: @ironstone13 `however still if they would not run on UI thread - the UI would not freeze` is not correct. Tasks send more messages than UI can handle them(Don't forget UI updates are slow.)

Comment: @L.B, oh yes - I clearly see it now `RefreshView` is obviously inside the loop - thanks for pointing that out, I was *wrong*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` which is supposed to schedule the tasks to run on the same thread as the calling one, which in your case is UI thread.

Offload all your work to background threads, and only marshal the ui refresh operations to your UI thread by using `BeginInvoke`

Also you absolutely have to call `await Task.Delay(xxx)` inside of your `while` loops, otherwise there are no delays between cycles, and they are very CPU intensive, and schedule too many UI updates

To quote MSDN on [TaskScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx)

> You can use the TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext method
>   to specify that a task should be scheduled to run on a particular
>   thread. This is useful in frameworks such as Windows Forms and Windows
>   Presentation Foundation where access to user interface objects is
>   often restricted to code that is running on the same thread on which
>   the UI object was created. For more information, see How to: Schedule
>   Work on the User Interface (UI) Thread.
>
> The following example uses the
>   TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext method in a Windows
>   Presentation Foundation (WPF) app to schedule a task on the same
>   thread that the user interface (UI) control was created on.